# iPhone 13 pro search refreshing on input

Tags: iphone, ios, search

I just upgraded to the new iPhone 13 pro and after setting it up I noticed that the search keeps refreshing when I enter a specific characters… :)
Any ideas what can be wrong?
[Video](https://youtu.be/tlrBBExSCjo)

iOS 15.1 (19B5052f)

Comment: Did you update it yet? Mine came with iOS 15 but immediately wanted to update to… iOS 15. I can only assume one was a 'not quite GM' release it was loaded with a few weeks ago at manufacture. I understand today there's also a 15.0.1 which is probably worth a go.

Comment: Forbes magazine seems rather unimpressed so far - https://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2021/10/02/apple-ios-1501-release-should-you-upgrade-free-iphone-upgrade/ [I was so unimpressed I sent my 13 back:\]

Comment: I was running beta on my old iPhone, when I transferred the data from old iPhone I had to use beta with the new one as well. So as in my original question I m running 15.1 beta. There was no problems like this with my old iPhone X though :)

Comment: Ah, didn't spot you were on beta. For any beta you need to raise it as a bug report with Apple.

Comment: @MateuszCiężczak If I remember correctly you can revert to normal stable versions by deleting the profile in settings.

Comment: Reverting profile in settings does not immediately brings you back from beta version. I need to wait for the next update